# Flex - changes to mxml not reflected in browser

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, flexbuilder, mxml

I have a Flex project and am using a trial version of Adobe Flex Builder 3 to build it.

I do the following:
1. Change an mxml file in the project (for simplicity, assume I changed the text in a label).
2. Right click on the project, Export, Release Build
3. Right click on the main mxml file, Run As -> Flex Application

A browser window opens, everything runs fine, but I cannot see the change I made in step 1.

I thought the browser (tried with IE, Chrome) might be caching stuff, so I tried after deleting all temporary internet files, but I see the same behavior.

Am I being dumb and missing something or is there something going on here?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I found that it was a problem with my code, nothing to do with the build process. 

I forgot Rule #1 of coding: Its always your fault ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check the timestamp on your .swf in your release folder. You might be running from a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL of the flex app in your browser to see if its running the debug version or the release version.

> file:///C:/ASWorkspace/FlexTest/**bin-debug**/FlexTest.html

When you run a flex app, flex builder normally runs the debug version. Exporting the release build is done when the project is completed - release build won't have any debug information in it and hence will be compact. If you have selected `Build Automatically` in the Project menu, the debug version will be recompiled automatically when you save a file. You can just hit F11 to run it.